# How to stay connected to an Android service between multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have multiple activities and one service. In `MainActivity` I successfully connect to service (using a class that implements `ServiceConnection` + `bindService()` + `startService()`) but when I try to apply same method in other activity I see in LogCat a error:

```
01-15 22:29:37.438: ERROR/ActivityThread(12206): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked:  
    Activity com.app.liviu.simpleMusicPlayer.PlaylistActivity has leaked ServiceConnection  
    com.app.liviu.simpleMusicPlayer.PlaylistActivity$CounterServiceConnection@43713c90  
    that was originally bound here.
```

Is it possible to connect to a service in an other way: something like to make static my `CounterServiceConnection` object in `MainActivity` and use it in the second one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error message is fairly self-explanatory: you are leaking a `ServiceConnection`, by which Android means you are calling `bindService()` but are not calling `unbindService()`, and the activity that called `bindService()` was destroyed. Make sure you call `unbindService()` in `onDestroy()`, if not sooner.

> something like to make static my
>   CounterServiceConnection object in
>   MainActivity and use it in the seconde
>   one?

No.

Comment: this is saying what the error is, not how to solve the problem

Comment: I got this error message by calling bindService, then bindService again in the same Activity

Comment: I am calling unbindService (this) onDestroy. To bind I am calling `boolean bindResult = bindService(new Intent(     Consts.MARKET_BILLING_SERVICE_ACTION), this, // ServiceConnection.
     Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)`. What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it from a separate thread as long as you install a looper in that thread